# Prevent particles at the same place?

Tags: particles

I try a simple particle system, with this group on the layer 2 :
[image: the group]

The result, placing it at Vertices places on a grid, using this group, is like :
[image: the result]

The problem is that sometimes 2 or 3 objects are at the same time on the same place... I didn't found anywhere how to disallow that, I would like to have just 1 object at random places (less or equal to the number of vertices)
Thank you !

## [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27382)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this way may meet your needs:

[image]

See key settings marked in the image above, very intuitive I suppose.

Comment: I really need it to be on vertices (probably on a more complicated surface), not necessary like a grid, and not on faces :(

Comment: Sure, as I said, then change it to **Verts** as you want, and set an appropriate emit number. Is that OK?

Comment: No, that is why I asked : I set a certain number of objects to be on vertices, but sometimes they overlap. If I disable "Random" (as said with Vader in the other answer) the objects are placed in a certain order (I can enable Pick Random). When I populate all the grid this is OK, but when I just want, for example, to create 50 objects on 100 vertices, I obtain without Random : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/910957bb1.png With Random : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/596547bb2.png overlaping :/ File uploaded in question

Comment: I've updated my answer. Then why not enable **Pick Random** while disable **Random**? The new way I suggest allows you to randomly pick vertices on the mesh by vertex group, if that's what's acceptable.

Comment: Very nice ! Vertex group is exactly the kind of thing I need ! Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: OK. A small tip: you can randomly select expected number of vertices by the **Select Random** function, then Hit F6 to adjust the percentage value, the total number of selected vertices can be monitored simultaneously in the top **Info** bar. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 3):

Disable Random in the particle emitter tab. This will only use each part once as long at there are not more part than there are particles.

[image]

Also if you are emitting from *Verts* or *Faces* you need to limit the number of particles and you want to populate the entire mesh:

- Verts: number of verts in mesh + 1
- Faces: number of faces in mesh

I am not sure why but for Verts you need to add another 1 so that all verts have some mesh on them

---

[image]

**[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27380)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) but I probably misspoke, I want it to be random (less or equal to the number of vertices), without more than 1 object to be at the same place, is it possible ?

Comment: you mean that you want the number of particles emitted to be random?

Comment: no I mean for example I have 100 vertices on my grid. But I only want to put 50 objects on some vertices (I did it on the screenshots of my question), the problem is that sometimes more than 1 object is put on the same vertices, I don't want it.
Moreover if I disable Random in the particle emitter tab, objects are put in the order ; one green, then one brown, then one purple, repeated. I want it random, on random places.

Comment: @Mizur for me it does them randomly. I will upload a screenshot

Comment: It is what happen when you disable Random ? (I guess no) never overlaping each other ?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Wtf. Could you upload your example somewhere ? I would like to compare it to mine :)

Comment: sure, give me a sec

Comment: Thank you ! But I really don't understand... I did exactly as you did and I have the same result I had... Without Random : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/910957bb1.png With Random : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/596547bb2.png overlaping again...

Comment: your looks weird, idk why

Comment: uplosd your blend file so I can see

Comment: File uploaded on question post