# Bookshelf Drivers (Possible to add/subtract books using drivers)?

Tags: modeling, animation, drivers

I have a bookshelf modeled and a group of 10 books (so as to not make the bookshelf look repeated), is it possible to create a driver to just drag up/down the amount of books on the shelf???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use particle system to emit the books from vertices:

[image]

The emitter is a subdivided plane, the origin of the book group (only 3 books on layer 2) is set to the bottom of the book.

Demofile: http://pasteall.org/blend/29436

Particle settings:

Uncheck Random under 'Emit from:'

[image]

Related: [Prevent particles at the same place?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/prevent-particles-at-the-same-place)

Comment: I see some books stacking on top of each other. How can I solve this?

Comment: @WorldSEnder I guess you emitted more particles than there're vertices to emit from. Either subdivide the emitter a bit more or reduce the number of particles.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Sorry I didn't notice that I posted it with checked Random. Uncheck Random under 'Emit from:'